# "Failure to send mail" Error

Tags: vb.net

I've been working on a college project that allows email reminders to be sent to specific customers. I'm running into a couple of problems that in I cannot actually send the email. It keeps giving me the error message "Failure to send mail" Which doesn't give me much to work off. Here is my code, any help would be extremely appreciated.

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Mail

    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("email@gmail.com", "password")
    SmtpServer.Port = 587
    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
    mail.To.Add("recievingemail@hotmail.co.uk")
    mail.From = New MailAddress("email@gmail.com")
    mail.Subject = "Match Reminder"
    mail.Body = "A reminder that you have an upcoming match this week, please check match details."
    SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```

Comment: When you catch your `SmtpException` and inspect it in the debugger, what is the exception subclass and value of the `InnerException` property?

Comment: Sorry, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Wrap your `.Send(mail)` method-call in a `Try/Catch` block to catch an `SmtpException`, then run your program in the debugger and inspect the caught exception in the Quick Watch tool.

Comment: I've done what was said but I haven't got any value?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint in the `Catch` block? Did the exception object appear in the Locals or Autos windows?

Comment: I added a breakpoint next to the smtpserver.send(mail) line.

Comment: Where was the try catch block meant to go between?